# Best way to import C++ vcxproj project into a testing project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, testing, msbuild, project

I have a fairly large C++ project which exposes a much smaller public user interface via a C-style API/dll. Each call in the public API involves a lot of internal logic, and I'd like to be able to write tests for that internal logic.

The project structure is summarized as follows: a `.vcxproj` references a `.def` file defining the public API, and a `.props` file which actually defines all the include paths, sources to be compiled, etc.

Now as I said, I'd like to test the project's internal functionality. We already have a functional separate test `.vcxproj` project right now, but it can't reference the main project via a `<ProjectReference/>` because that would just expose the public API to the test project (correct me if I'm wrong). Therefore the current test project includes the main one just by directly importing its `.props` like so:

```
<Import Project="..\..\dll\Main.props" />
```

Honestly this would be acceptable but for the fact that all of the main project files now show up as part of the test project in the solution explorer, which can make it annoying to find the test files themselves among all the "real" code.

I was wondering if anyone had solutions/suggestions as to what to do here. For instance, is there a way to import the props file such that the files from `Main.props` are automatically hidden somehow? Even restructuring the main project to include the tests, eg

```
Main/
    main.vcxproj
    src/
    tests/
```

could be an option, provided that the tests could be compiled without affecting the user-facing dll

Comment: "*the files from `Main.props`*" That is rather unusual. What `.props` files are commonly used for is to share *settings* between projects, not the list of source files.

Comment: dxiv Yes, I've suspected for a while that our build conventions are wrong. Lets say that we I moved the list of files over into the vcxproj, would it be any easier to accomplish what I'm going for?